# PyCharm sidebar randomly disappears

Tags: pycharm

I have occasionally encountered the issue that PyCharm's sidebar randomly disappears.  I was wondering what the problem might be. [image]

Comment: Perhaps you can describe some things you've did in the past that led to this?

Comment: I can't think of anything at the moment. The thing is that, if I click on the other tab in the run window (here both are named scratch_24 (1), if I click on the other one) it is not there. When running some scripts, it is there, for some other scripts, it is not there.